# How to Automatically Encrypt Web.config after installation

Tags: asp.net, security, encryption, web, web-config

I created a web app. Now I want to Encrypt the Web.config of my application.

I've tried the CMD method and it do worked. But  I want to make it auto encypted after installation. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to encrypt whole web.config file. If you only keep connection string variable in web.config, you can only encrypt it.

You can use following command to encrypt connectionStrings.

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/SampleApplication"
```

After process your web.config files looks like following example.

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
      <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
         <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
         <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
               <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
               <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                  <KeyName>RSA Key
                  </KeyName>
               </KeyInfo>
               <CipherData>
                  <CipherValue>WcFEbDX8VyLfAsVK8g6hZVAG1674ZFc1kWH0BoazgOwdBfinhcAmQmnIn0oHtZ5tO2EXGl+dyh10giEmO9NemH4YZk+iMIln+ItcEay9CGWMXSen9UQLpcQHQqMJErZiPK4qPZaRWwqckLqriCl9X8x9OE7jKIsO2Ibapwj+1Jo=
                  </CipherValue>
               </CipherData>
            </EncryptedKey>
         </KeyInfo>
         <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>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
            </CipherValue>
         </CipherData>
      </EncryptedData>
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what I wanna do is during installation, there will be an automated encryption of the connectionstring in my web.config. I don't wanna use CMD. Is it possible?